# Update en laravel con primary key distinto a id

Tags: laravel

Estoy comenzando a trabajar con laravel, pero ya la base de datos estaba creada y en ninguna de las tablas la clave primaria tiene por nombre `id`.

La tabla roles tiene su clave primaria `id_role` al intentar hacer el *update* me indica el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Invalid column name 'id'. [20018] (severity 16) [update [roles] set [COD_ROLE] = '1111',
>   [DES_ROLE] = 'Sysadmin2', [FDM_ROLE] = '2018-07-31' where [id] is
>   null] (SQL: update [roles] set [COD_ROLE] = 1111, [DES_ROLE] =
>   Sysadmin2, [FDM_ROLE] = 2018-07-31 where [id] is null)

En mi modelo *role* ya redefiní la clave primaria:

```
class role extends Model
{
     /*
     Modificar convenciones de Laravel:
     */   
    //Para indicar que la tabla del modelo no usará los campos created_at y updated_at
    public $timestamps = false;
    //Indicar que la clave de la tabla no es id sino id_role
    protected $primary_key = 'ID_ROLE';
}
```

Teniendo ésto en el controlador:

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $rol = role::where("id_role", '=', $request['ID_ROLE'])->first();

        $rol->COD_ROLE = $request['COD_ROLE'];
        $rol->DES_ROLE = $request['DES_ROLE'];
        $rol->OBS_ROLE = $request['OBS_ROLE'];
        $rol->FDM_ROLE = Date('Y-m-d');
        $rol->EST_ROLE = $request['EST_ROLE'];
        $rol->save();
    }
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme e indicarme qué estoy haciendo mal, por qué no funciona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el modelo agrega esto:

```
public function getKeyName(){
    return "id_role";
}
```

Comment: Gracias!!!! Lo hice y funcionó, además cambié protected $primary_key = 'ID_ROLE'; por

    protected $primaryKey  = 'ID_ROLE';

Comment: Falta la explicación de ¿por qué no funciona? lo que tiene actualmente el OP.

Comment: De nada @MariaVirginia y bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español.

Comment: @Shaz, no funcionaba porque Laravel, por defecto considera que la **primary key** es **id** si no se dice lo contrario. Eso se consigue redefiniendo el comportamiento de la función que devuelve dicho parámetro y que usa Laravel de forma interna. Nota: por cierto, ya que tienes el nivel de Certified developper en Laravel, podías haber explicado tu ese "detalle"

Comment: @JuanJoseBurgosVeiga no se trata de explicarlo porque pueda conocer más o no sobre Laravel (de hecho conozco la respuesta y no es del todo correcto lo que dices en este caso), se trata de sustentar las respuestas que damos en la comunidad, no es solo poner código y decir "usa este código, espero que sirva".

Comment: @Sanz, Como experto que eres en el tema y tu reputación, puedes editar la respuesta para mejorarla. Lo que dije es cierto en el caso concreto, ya que en el código no ha precisado correctamente la clave del modelo. O se define correctamente la clave o se reescribe la función que la devuelve (que es la solución dada, aunque sea preferible definir correctamente la variable).

Comment: Continuación: Si conoces mas información, solo tienes que completar y mejorar la respuesta para que toda la comunidad aprendamos de los expertos, en vez de "quejarte" por la respuesta, que vistos muchas preguntas, parece ser que es la prioridad aquí, es decir, preguntar, poner código y responder basándose en el código (Prefiero lo que tu propones, pero no es lo que se suele ver)